# Grafana URL Alerting

Tags: grafana

I configured my grafana alerts to be directed to telegram,
but the url in the message is localhost:3000
I changed the domain already in grafana.ini but it didn't work, I still get localhost:3000 in the alert message.
Are there any other configurations to be made?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grafana is generating links with Base URL : http://localhost:3000 instead of using my url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795402/grafana-is-generating-links-with-base-url-http-localhost3000-instead-of-usi)

Answer (score 2):

> Configure the root_url option of [server] in your Grafana config file or env variable GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL to https://grafana.company.com/

From [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795402/grafana-is-generating-links-with-base-url-http-localhost3000-instead-of-usi?rq=1) Question and answer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049258/grafana-email-does-not-have-the-right-url-when-root-url-is-set-to-protocols?rq=1) shows to set root URL As well. I'd say this is likely a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change root_url under grafana.ini something like:

```
[server]
root_url = https://xyz.xxx.com
```

Answer (score 1):

For kubernetes chart, please add those for grafana:

```
grafana:
  env:
    GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: "https://your.url/"
  notifiers:
    notifiers.yaml:
      notifiers:
      - name: telegram
        type: telegram
        uid: telegram
        is_default: true
        settings:
          bottoken: "yourbottoken"
          chatid: "-yourchatid"
```

and use `uid: "telegram"` in the provisioned dashboards. Please note, you should not miss quotes, `https://` or `http://` part and even the end `/` in `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL`